# Where do I put the ExpiresDefault directive? I'm using CodeIgniter

Tags: apache, caching, codeigniter

I'm following the High Performance Websites book and the advice is to put this:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(gif|jpg|js|css)$">
  ExpiresDefault "access plus 10 years"
</FilesMatch>
```

Where do I put it anyway? I'm using COdeIgniter. And I have access to my httpd.conf file.

Answer (score 3):

You actually should put it in your `.htaccess` file in your site root.

Additionally, You can put it in the `<Directory></Directory>` block in your httpd.conf but it's probably better off in your `.htaccess` in my opinion.

Comment: I read that .htaccess is slower because it will scan all the directory?

Comment: `.htaccess` is so widely used, I highly doubt it's going to be much slower. You're welcome to put it in the `<Directory></Directory>` tag in your `http.conf` if you like. It's all the same in the end.